# Finding max elem from a map1 not in map2

Tags: c++, input, stl, maps

So I have 2 STL maps in which I'm reading data from a file. It reads data into one until the read in data is 0, then it moves on to the second map and stores data into that one.

I'm trying to find the max element into map1 which is not in map2. This is my code for it:

```
map<int, int> dataMap1;
map<int, int>:: reverse_iterator i;
map<int, int> dataMap2;
map<int, int>:: iterator j;

for(i = dataMap1.rbegin(); i != dataMap1.rend(); i++) {
    largestNum = i->first;
    j = dataMap2.find(largestNum);
    if(largestNum > j->first) {
        cout << largestNum << endl;
        break;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work as intended. It sometimes gives me the correct output but other times it gives me the wrong answer.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Thanks.

EDIT: example data - 
2

4

3

6

5

9

0   // above this is stored in map1, 0 and everything below is stored in 
       map2

1

4

5

3

Comment: Have you taken steps to ensure `j = dataMap2.find(largestNum);` can find `largestNum`? If it cannot, `find` will return `dataMap2.end()`, and you can't use the end iterator for much of anything beyond testing for the end. `j->first` could be invalid.

Comment: Re-read question. It seems the point is to find the element that isn't in both maps. When you find it, it will be by testing `j == dataMap2.end()`.

Comment: Unrelated: If the second `int` in `map<int, int> dataMap1;`is the same as the first `int` consider using a `std::set` instead.

Comment: how would I do that? Also, is an ordered map the best data structure for this or is there a better, more efficient data structure to solve this problem?

Comment: To answer that I'd have to see what the data looks like and how you are using it. Take a look at the [Algorithms Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). There's neat stuff in it like `std::set_intersection`  and `max_element` that could turn the job into a one-liner.

Comment: If I just have two lists of numbers and no other constraints, I'd read list one into a `std::set`, then remove all of the elements in list two from the `set`. What's left I'd feed into `max_element`. Might not be the fastest, bit it's only a few lines of code.

Comment: I edited the post to include sample data.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you just got the `if` test wrong.

```
for (i = dataMap1.rbegin(); i != dataMap1.rend(); i++) {
    largestNum = i->first;
    j = dataMap2.find(largestNum);
    if (j == dataMap2.end()) { // if largestNum not in dataMap2
        cout << largestNum << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I figured as much but what would I change if it was?

Comment: if `dataMap2.find()` returns iterator, which is not equal to `dataMap2.end()` then `j->first` is equal to `largestNum`, so you do not need to do anything.

Comment: when I use a different file to read data from, it still outputs 5 eventhough thats not the correct answer. Do you know why it might do that?

Comment: @JapFios Not unless I can see that file and the code you use to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
auto it = std::find_if( dataMap1.rbegin(), dataMap1.rend(), [&dataMap2]( const auto &p ) {
    return dataMap2.count( p.first ) == 0;
} );
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/c6fpuD)

Comment: when I use a different file to read data from, it still outputs 5 eventhough thats not the correct answer. Do you know why it might do that?

Comment: @JapFios sorry my telepathy machine is broken today